# Кнопка, которая выводит числа в консоль от 1 до n. В зависимости от числа нажатий

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть простая html страница с одной кнопкой. При каждом нажатии будет генерироваться список с цифрами. При первом нажатии должна выводится цифра один, при втором два и так далее. Пока я хочу добиться того, чтобы цифры выводились в консоль. Я попробовал разместить обработчик события внутрь цикла. Но в консоль выводятся поcледнее значение цикла. Что я сделал не так?

```js
var b = document.getElementById('button');
var c = function() {
  console.log(i);
}
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  b.addEventListener("click", c, false);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="Button" id="button" value="Click Me">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь цикл не нужен, вообще. Нужна внешняя переменная, которая и будет выводится

```js
var b = document.getElementById('button');
var i = 0;
var c = function() {
  console.log(i);
  i++;
}

b.addEventListener("click", c, false);
```

```html
<input type="button" name="Button" id="button" value="Click Me">
```

Comment: Спасибо, мысль не туда зашла.

Comment: @Streammer "Спасибо" - галочкой на ответ не поставишь как говорится.

Answer (score 3):

Можно еще и так...

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var i = 0;
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(i++);
})
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>
```